# Why does a tag with position fixed have a slightly different position on different html pages?

Tags: html, css

[image][image][image]I have a tag *(div.natalie p)* that kind of jumps on different html pages (index.html, about.html, shop.html, work.html etc.) It has a position fixed and all the css is the same, so technically it should be in the exact same position on each page, but it's not. It's odd because I have a nav tag on the other side that works and has the exact same position on each of the html pages. I hope the attached images make my problem a little clearer.

```css
div.natalie p {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "MenaGrotesk-Light";
  font-size: 16px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40px;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 0);
  z-index: 5;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 40px;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%, 0);
}

nav a {
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: "MenaGrotesk-Light";
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.1s ease-out;
}

nav a:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 3px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="natalie">
  <p>Natalie Taylor</p>
</div>
<nav>
  <a class="hover" href="index.html">work</a>
  <a class="hover" href="shop.html">shop</a>
  <a class="hover" href="about.html">about</a>
  <a class="hover" href="impressum.html">imprint</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: it would be useful if you could post the code for a page that works and one that doesn't

Comment: Is it possible some pages have overflow, and others don't? Considering it's anchored to the right that's likely the culprit. Setting the body to overflow-y: scroll should resolve that.

Comment: @j08691 the code for the div.natalie p and nav is the exact same on all pages

Comment: @will no, I just tried that and that didn't seem to be the issue.. any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe try top 50vh instead of top 50%? Do you have the page up on the net anywhere? I'll need to inspect to come up with anything definitive

Comment: @will nope, just tried it and 50vh doesn't change anything :( No it's not up yet. I'll finish the rest of the site and put it up in a few days and hopefully someone will see what's going on. Thanks anyway!